# Can't remove objects from input field in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to delete data from input field, but it's not deleting.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            name: 'item 1',
            id: '4'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 2',
            id: '3'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 3',
            id: '2'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 4',
            id: '1'
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.delete = function (item) {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'id'" ng-click="delete(item)">
        <span>
            Hello, {{item.name}}!
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="items" />
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/30/).

```
$scope.delete = function (item) {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
```

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-model="items" />` why you have the array `items` as the `ng-model`?

Comment: bcos I have to pass this array to service

Comment: What do you really want? When you are typing the name of `item` and on clicking on a button say `delete`. then want to delete particular item fromt he array?

Comment: bcos I have to pass this array to service using this input field. If data is not deleted it will pass same data to the service right? just assume like you are in edit mode, and want to delete objects from a array called admins, so when you updating data these deleted objects should not be counted

Comment: you can simply inject service into controller assign it. why you need input?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and please do add more information, like why are you using input field to delete. What is you service about to do etc.

Comment: bcos I have to pass this array to service using this input field. If data is not deleted it will pass same data to the service right? just assume like you are in edit mode, and want to delete objects from a array called admins, so when you updating data these deleted objects should not be counted @SyamPillai

Comment: `items` is a object it is unable to bind in a single input field, that because it show `[object][object]`.
You should skip this input field, you can get updated `items` from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your UI a little bit.

Added a button there to `delete` selected `item`

Just give the **name of the item to be deleted in the input field**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            name: 'item 1',
            id: '4'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 2',
            id: '3'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 3',
            id: '2'
        },
        {
            name: 'item 4',
            id: '1'
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.delete = function (item) {
     for(var x in $scope.items){
       if($scope.items[x].name == item){
         $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf($scope.items[x]), 1);
           $scope.toRemove = '' // clear input field after deleting
          }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'id'">
        <span>
            Hello, {{item.name}}!
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="toRemove" />
    <button ng-click="delete(toRemove)">delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Here is the working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/34/)**

Comment: @Kranthi updated the answer. Now you can check it's working on the snippet given above

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is

```
$scope.delete = function (item) {
     $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
}
$scope.items.indexOf(item) -- You cannot fetch index of an "object" in an array by directly using "indexOf(item)".
```

Try this

```
$scope.delete = function (item) { 
        // fetch the position of item in items array
        position = $scope.items.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(item.name);
        $scope.items.splice(position, 1);
        console.log($scope.items);
  }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fCiXRZXY6zkQivYX50zj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe this meets your requirement.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.items = [
                     {name : 'item1', id : '4'},
                     {name : 'item2', id : '3'},
                     {name : 'item3', id : '2'},
                     {name : 'item4', id : '1'}
                     ];
     $scope.addTextField = function(name){
      $scope.textFiles = name;
     };
     $scope.remove = function(item){
      for (var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
       if($scope.items[i].name == item){
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf($scope.items[i]), 1);
        $scope.textFiles = '';
       }
      }
     };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'id'" ng-click="addTextField(item.name);">
   Click me {{item.name}}!
  </div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="textFiles"><input type="button" value="X" ng-click="remove(textFiles);">
 </div>
```